# C4 which shape was clicked?

Tags: touch, interaction, c4

I have added 42 shapes to the canvas of a C4 app. How can I determine which one of the shapes has been touched by a user?

I add the shapes as follows:

```
#import "C4Workspace.h"

@implementation C4WorkSpace{
    C4Shape *greyRect;
}

-(void)setup {
    int imageWidth=53.53;
    int imageHeight=65.1;
    for (int i=0; i<42; i++) {
        int xMultiplier=(i)%6;
        int yMultiplier= (i)/6;
        int xPos=xMultiplier*imageWidth;
        int yPos=yMultiplier*imageHeight;
        greyRect=[C4Shape rect:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
        greyRect.fillColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0];
        greyRect.lineWidth=2;
        greyRect.strokeColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.7 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
        [self listenFor:@"touchesBegan" fromObject:greyRect andRunMethod:@"highlightLetter"];

        [self.canvas addShape:greyRect];
    }
}

-(void)highlightLetter{
    C4Log(@"highlightLetter");
}

@end
```

I pretty much only need to know which number[i] the clicked rect has.

But I don't know how to access that after running the line: `[self listenFor:@"touchesBegan" fromObject:greyRect andRunMethod:@"highlightLetter"];`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [WHO SAID WHAT?](http://www.c4ios.com/tutorials/notifications#_who_said_what) part of the notifications tutorial on C4 site.

This part of the notifications tutorial explains how to react to a given object's notification and actually figure out which object just broadcast that notification.

The trick is in building a method that accepts the notification:

```
-(void)highlightLetter:(NSNotification *)notification {
    C4Shape *shape = (C4Shape *)notification.object;
    //do stuff to the shape
}
```

Also, remember that *because the method takes a* **variable** you have to include the `:` in the name of the method like so:

```
[self listenFor:@"touchesBegan" 
     fromObject:greyRect 
   andRunMethod:@"highlightLetter:"];
```

Comment: this is doing the trick and I adapted it the way I needed! thanks!!